# Can I put Create/Alter Table, Procedure, Column, Views, etc inside Transaction?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

My simple question is, can I put Create/Alter Table, Procedure, Column, Views, etc statements inside Transaction? What I mean is this? Will the below statements be valid?

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION [Tran1]
BEGIN TRY
    --CREATE ALTER Table Procedure 
    --CREATE ALTER Table Procedure 
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION [Tran1];
    DECLARE @ErrorNumber nchar(5), @ErrorMessage nvarchar(2048);
    SELECT
        @ErrorNumber = RIGHT('00000' + ERROR_NUMBER(), 5),
        @ErrorMessage = @ErrorNumber + ' ' + ERROR_MESSAGE();
    RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, 16, 1);
END CATCH
```

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4356/how-to-use-transactions-with-sql-server-ddl

Comment: I'm always stunned at questions like this which must surely take longer to write out than to just simply *try it*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am aware DDL sentences can be transactional while in read-committed isolation mode (pessimistic), which is the default mode.

[msdn Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191544.aspx)

Comment: Found this link. Seems you are saying fine. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191544.aspx

Comment: @user960567 - One issue you will have with your proposed structure is that the `CREATE PROC ...` needs to be a batch on its own so will need to be `EXEC('CREATE PROC ...')` to run in a child batch.

Answer (score 1):

[Transact-SQL Statements Allowed in Transactions (Sql Server 2008):](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191544%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) You can use all Transact-SQL statements in an explicit transaction, except for the following statements:

```
ALTER DATABASE
DROP DATABASE
ALTER FULLTEXT CATALOG  
DROP FULLTEXT CATALOG
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX    
DROP FULLTEXT INDEX
BACKUP  
RECONFIGURE
CREATE DATABASE
RESTORE
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG
UPDATE STATISTICS
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX
```

You also cannot use the following:

Full-text system stored procedures in an explicit transaction. For more information, see Full-Text Search Stored Procedures (Transact-SQL).

sp_dboption to set database options or use any system procedures that modify the master database inside explicit or implicit transactions.